# Function not triggering on click

Tags: reactjs

The function is not triggering when I press on the NavButton component.

I'm new to React.js and I'm trying to call the setCurrentActive function when NavButton gets clicked, but nothing happens. Am I doing it wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../css-files/navbar.css';
import logo from '../assets/svg/logo.svg';

export default function Navbar() {

    function setCurrentActive() {
        console.log("works")
    } 
    
    return (
            <div className="Navbar" id="myNavBar">
            <img className="logo" src={logo} alt=''/>
            <ul className="links" id="Links">
                <NavButton id={1}label="ACASĂ" onClick={setCurrentActive}/>
                <NavButton id={2}label="ACUSTICE"/>
                <NavButton id={3}label="CLASICE"/>
                <NavButton id={4}label="ELECTRICE"/>
            </ul>
            <a href="/" className="icon">
                <img src="../assets/png/menu.png" alt=""/>
            </a>
            </div>
    );
}

function NavButton(props) {
    const [name, setName] = useState(props.id === 1 ? "active" : "");

    function changeName() {
        if (name === "")
            setName("active");
        else
            setName("");
    }

    return (
        <li className={name} onClick={changeName}>
            {props.label}
        </li>   
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavButton` is a custom component, so it doesn't have an `onClick` listener, so if you are passing any props to the' custom' component, you need to handle it.

To handle that, you just need to pass `if (props.onClick) props.onClick();` in your native onClick button listener.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../css-files/navbar.css';
import logo from '../assets/svg/logo.svg';

export default function Navbar() {

    function setCurrentActive() {
        console.log("works")
    } 
    
    return (
            <div className="Navbar" id="myNavBar">
            <img className="logo" src={logo} alt=''/>
            <ul className="links" id="Links">
                <NavButton id={1}label="ACASĂ" onClick={setCurrentActive}/>
                <NavButton id={2}label="ACUSTICE"/>
                <NavButton id={3}label="CLASICE"/>
                <NavButton id={4}label="ELECTRICE"/>
            </ul>
            <a href="/" className="icon">
                <img src="../assets/png/menu.png" alt=""/>
            </a>
            </div>
    );
}

function NavButton(props) {
    const [name, setName] = useState(props.id === 1 ? "active" : "");

    function changeName() {
        if (props.onClick) props.onClick();
        if (name === "")
            setName("active");
        else
            setName("");
    }

    return (
        <li className={name} onClick={changeName}>
            {props.label}
        </li>   
    )
}
```